# p_GeoStats metrics data seem to be inflated

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

The AdWords GeoStats clicks data seems to be inflated (nearly 4-5 times) as compared to the AdWords account and campaign stats data in bigquery. Please help me understand.

```
SELECT SUM(Clicks) FROM `ProjectName.GoogleAds_Reports.p_CampaignStats_XXXXXX` WHERE Date >= "2019-01-01" AND Date <= "2019-01-31"
as compared to 
SELECT SUM(Clicks) FROM `ProjectName.GoogleAds_Reports.p_GeoStats_XXXXXX` WHERE Date >= "2019-01-01" AND Date <= "2019-01-31"
```

**Expected** - `AccountStats Clicks = 2035413`

**Actual** - `GeoStats Clicks = 8422608`

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you're not filtering for `LocationType`, which in your case should be set to `LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE`.

```
SELECT SUM(Clicks) FROM `ProjectName.GoogleAds_Reports.p_GeoStats_XXXXXX` WHERE Date >= "2019-01-01" AND Date <= "2019-01-31"
AND LocationType = "LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE"
```